# How to make database backup file contains different data only

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In my windows application when I backup my SQL Server 2008 R2 database, the backup file will contain database schema and table data, but when try to take backup more and more the backup file size will swell

Is there a way to retain the backup only recently within the file?

This is the code used for backup

```
connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString);

string location = "";
SqlDataReader reader = null;

try
{
    reader = DataAccess.SelectCommand(StoredName,null);

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        location = reader[0].ToString();
    }

    reader.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    reader.Close();
    connection.Close();

    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Exception occured.\nMessage: {0}", ex.Message), "fawzy Mokhtar", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    return 0;
}

Server sqlServer = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));

Backup dbBackup = new Backup();

try
{
    dbBackup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
    dbBackup.Database = DBName;
    dbBackup.BackupSetName = string.Format("{0} backup set.", DBName);
    dbBackup.BackupSetDescription = string.Format("Database: {0}. Date: {1}.", DBName, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:m"));
    dbBackup.MediaDescription = "Disk";

    BackupDeviceItem device = new BackupDeviceItem(location + DBName + ".bak", DeviceType.File);
    dbBackup.Devices.Add(device);

    dbBackup.SqlBackup(sqlServer);
    return 1;
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    dbBackup.Abort();

    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Exception occured.\nMessage: {0}", exc.Message), "fawzy mokhtar", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    return 0;
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: You need to study the [various types of backup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186289%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you can create a **differential backup** to contain only the changes since the last full backup. But once in a while, you need to have a full backup again - even if the file size will grow over time!

Answer (score 0):

As marc_s said in his comment, you're looking for a differential backup. To do this with what you've got, at the Incremental property on your backup object to true.  Just make sure you're still taking a full backup from time to time!